# No request headers are being sent using .net-core

Tags: c#, .net-core, http-headers, http-post

I am writing a .NET core webservice (I will refer to this as "MyWs" from now on) that should trigger an endpoint of another webservice (I will refer to this as "OtherWs" from now on). When sending requests to OtherWs using postman everything works fine. 
However, when I try to reach OtherWs from MyWs I always get an "Unauthorized" response (401). Looking at the requests that are tracked by Fiddler (a tool I use to inspect http(s) traffic) it seems that no request headers are actually sent by MyWs even though they are configured in the code.

The way postman is configured can be seen in this screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/06VNh.png

The request in Fiddler can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/77gaS.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2kbc.jpg

Even though this works, there are two strange things at play here:

1. The authorization headers are not visible in Fiddler. I am however sure that the authorization header plays an important role because when I change it to a faulty value, I get an "Unauthorized" Response (401).
2. Even though I only fire one request, two requests are recorded by Fiddler. I think this might have to do with a redirect by the receiving server.

I have tried three different ways of creating the request.

**Attempt 1: Using Restsharp**

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> process()
        {   
            var client = new RestClient("https://host.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("servicename/endpoint", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic SecretToken");

            request.AddParameter("text/json",
                "{\"Key\":\"\",\"Order\":{\"DeliveryDate\":\"5/1/2020\",\"OrderLines\":[{\"ItemNr\":\"12345\",\"Quantity\":1,\"Description\":\"Some string\",\"QuantityPerUnit\":1}],\"Tries\":0}, \"Customernr\":\"123\"}"
                , ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
            return Ok(content);
        }
```

The `response` variable has a `StatusCode` `Unauthorized` when firing this request. The corresponding request in Fiddler can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9wlU.jpg

It stands out that there are no request-headers at all. Not an authorization header but also no Content-Type header for example even though the code above should set it.

**Attempt 2: Using `HttpRequestMessage`**

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> process2()
        {
            var relativeAddress = "https://host.com/servicename/endpoint";
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, relativeAddress);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic SecretToken");
            // request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.Content = new StringContent(
                "{\"Key\":\"\",\"Order\":{\"DeliveryDate\":\"5/1/2020\",\"OrderLines\":[{\"ItemNr\":\"12345\",\"Quantity\":1,\"Description\":\"Some string\",\"QuantityPerUnit\":1}],\"Tries\":0}, \"Customernr\":\"123\"}"
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");
            request.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var response = "";
            await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask => {
                response = responseTask.Result.Content.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
            });
            return Ok();
        }
```

In this case, the response also says `Unauthorized`.

The request in Fiddler looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Waa1B.jpg

**Attempt 3: Using `HttpWebRequest`**

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> process3()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://host.com/servicename/endpoint");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic SecretToken");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (response == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
            var json = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

            responseStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return Ok();
        }
```

In this case, the response says Unauthorized yet again. I didn't even add a body to this request but if I don't add a body with postman it throws a 500 so that proves that this approach doesn't work either.

The request in Fiddler looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOE7M.jpg

Something noteworthy to mention is that if I set the `AllowAutoRedirect` to `false` I get this error:

`WebException: The remote server returned an error: (307) Temporary Redirect.`

I am at a loss now as it seems that no headers are actually set for any of the requests I make with .NET. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction? I have a hunch that it has to do with the redirecting of the receiving server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET Core then you should always use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which has much better integration with framework.

First you need to create a wrapper class around `HttpClient` for your OtherWs.

Example:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApi1
{
    public class OtherWsClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public OtherWsClient(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<string> SendRequest()
        {
            var content = new StringContent(
                "{\"Key\":\"\",\"Order\":{\"DeliveryDate\":\"5/1/2020\",\"OrderLines\":[{\"ItemNr\":\"12345\",\"Quantity\":1,\"Description\":\"Some string\",\"QuantityPerUnit\":1}],\"Tries\":0}, \"Customernr\":\"123\"}",
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");

            var response = await _client.PostAsync("/otherwsapi", content);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var responseConent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseConent;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell framework about new `OtherWs` client in Startup class.

Example:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            .....

            services.AddHttpClient<OtherWsClient>((serviceProvider, client) =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("base url");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "secret token");
            });
        }
```

The only thing left is to inject the new client and use it in your main controller.

Example:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi1.Controllers
{
    public class MyWsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly OtherWsClient _otherWsClient;
        public MyWsController(OtherWsClient otherWsClient)
        {
            _otherWsClient = otherWsClient;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
        {
            var response = await _otherWsClient.SendRequest();

            return Content(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but unfortunately the headers are still not being set if I do it like you suggested. I also added this line to the startup:
`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));` but still no headers are set according to Fiddler resulting in the following error:
**HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).**

Comment: Can you debug the `OtherWs` source code  or it is an external service ?

Comment: We did not manage to fix the underlying problem but we found a workaround by adding `OtherWs` as a WCF reference. If I understand correctly, this feature of dotnet uses soap and it doesn't suffer from the authorization issue by doing it like this.